# Referencia a etiqueta

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo este código y esta función y quiero que el valor obtenido en la función lo pueda mandar a una label en mi archivo **index** para que el usuario lo vea.

por ejemplo si mi select option dice Rob mi etiqueta diga robertos

```js
$(function(){

  // Lista de empresas
  $.post( 'continentes.php' ).done( function(respuesta)
  {
    $( '#continentes' ).html( respuesta );
  });
  // lista de tiendas  
  $('#continentes').change(function()
  {
    var el_continente = $(this).val();
    
    // Lista de tiendas
    $.post( 'paises.php', { continente: el_continente} ).done( function( respuesta )
    {
      $( '#paises' ).html( respuesta );
    });
  });
  // Lista de Ciudades
  $( '#paises' ).change( function()
  {
    var pais = $(this).children('option:selected').html();
    alert( 'Lista de Ciudades de ' + pais );
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <title>Inicio De Inventario</title>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <link href="../../css/css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <script src="functions.js"></script>
 </head>
  <body> 
   <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
     <td style="background:url(../../images/topbaner.gif) repeat-y #d2e0f2;">
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
       <tr>
        <td width="56%"><img src="../../images/logo.gif" width="167" height="39" alt="Logo" /></td>
         <td width="44%" align="right" valign="bottom">
          <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
           <tr>
            <td width="60%" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="40%" align="right"><span style="padding-right:5px;">
             <strong>Fecha:&nbsp;<?php echo date('d-m-Y'); ?>
             </strong></span></td>
           </tr>
            <tr>
             <td align="right">
              <strong>Usuario:
              </strong> <em><?php echo $Session['FullName']; ?></em>
             </td>
              <td align="right"><strong><a href="../../logout.php">Terminar Sesi&oacute;n</a></strong></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
         </td>
       </tr>
      </table>
     </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>
       <tr>
        <td width="84%" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="border:1px solid #98c0f4;">
         <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
           <!--td valign="bottom" bgcolor="#d2e0f2" style="background-image:url(tab-strip-bg.gif); background-repeat:repeat-x; height:26px;"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"--><!--color de la tabla-->
           <tr>
            <td>
             <tr>
              <td width="81%">
               <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                 <td align="center"><div class="tabmenu" onClick="document.location.href='../index.php';">Inicio</div></td>
                </tr>
               </table>
              </td>
             </tr>
            </td>
           </tr>
          </tr>
         </table>
        </td>
       </tr>
      </td>
     </tr>    
    <td>
    <br><table width="98%" border="3" align="center" cellspacing="10">
     <tr>
      <td><h2><pre>Webinv    Gestion De Inventarios</pre></h2></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td align="left" border="1">Inicio De Inventario
       <form  action="" name="form1">
        <br>
        <table width="100%" border="0">
         <tr>
          <td width="10%" valign="bottom">&nbsp;<label>Empresa:</label></td>
          <td width="6%">
           <select name="continentes" id="continentes" >
             <option value="0">Seleccione</option>
           </select></td>
          <td>
          <label name="empresa" id "empresa"></label>
          </td>
          <td width="11%"><label>Fecha</label></td>
          <td width="40%"><?php echo date('d-m-Y'); ?></td>
         </tr>
          <tr>
          <td><br>&nbsp;<label>Almacen:</label></td>
          <td><br><select name="paises" id="paises">
             <option value="0">Seleccione</option>
            </select></td>
          <td><?php echo $el_continente; ?></td>
          <td>Folio De Inventario</td>
          <td><?php echo $el_continente; ?></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td><br>&nbsp;<label for="res">Responsable:</label></td>
          <td><br><select>
             <?php while ($row3=mysql_fetch_array($usur))
              {?>
             <option value="<?php echo $row3['usuario']?>"><?php echo $row3['usuario'];?></option>
              <?php } ?>
            </select></td>
          <td><em><?php echo $empr5['elemento'] ?></em></td>
          <td><label for="mot"> Motivo Del Inventario</label></td>
          <td><select>
             <?php while ($row4=mysql_fetch_array($moti))
             {?>
             <option value="<?php echo $row4['motivo']?>"><?php echo $row4['motivo'];?></option>
             <?php } ?>
             </select><label><em><?php echo $Session['FullName']; ?></em></label></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td><br>&nbsp;<label for="res">Tipo De Usuario:</label></td>
          <td>&nbsp;<br><em><?php echo $row3['tip_usuario']?></em></td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td></td>
         </tr>
        </table>
        <br> 
        <br> 
        <br>
       </form>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><form action="form.php" method="get" name="form2">
       <table width="1063" border="0">
        <tr>
         <td width="151"><h1><pre>Inventario Anterior</pre></h1></td>
         <td width="253"></td>
         <td width="237">&nbsp;</td>
         <td width="78">&nbsp;</td>
         <td width="322">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
        <td><br>Motivo De Inventario:</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><br>Fecha:</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
         <td><br>Responsable:</td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td><br>Ultimo Folio</td>
         <td></td>
          </tr>
       </table>
      </form></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
   </table>
     <tr><table width="98%" border="0" align="center">
      <tr>
       <td width="100%" align="right" border"0"><input name="Cancelar" type="reset" value="Restablecer" /><input name="Aceptar" type="submit" value="Enviar" /></td>
      </tr>
     </table>
      <td style="background:url(../../images/light-hd.gif) repeat-x #d2e0f2; height:26px; border-top:1px solid #98c0f4; border-bottom:1px solid #98c0f4; padding-left:5px; padding-right:5px;"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
       <tr>
        <td width="7%" align="right" >&nbsp; <a href="mailto:helphabers@gpohabers.com">Soporte</a></td>
       </tr>
      </td>
     </tr>
    </td>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola Jorge Ángel, te recomiendo encarecidamente que edites tu pregunta siguiendo esta guía: [mcve]. Solo coloca las partes mínimas necesarias para comprender tu pregunta.

Comment: gracias por la observación ya cambie la pregunta